# powershell: como hacer funcionar un array en una query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

como puedo hacer que en mi query cambie la palabra buin por las que estan en el array

```
$DB_NAME_M = "<A>(<B>)";

$TIMESTAMPP = Get-Date;
$TIMESTAMPP = $TIMESTAMPP.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

#Arrays
$DB_ARRAYY = @( "elquisco", "imelbosque", "macul", "lareina", "mpinto", "penalolen", "coquimbo");

    #Replace timestamp
    $DB_NAME_MIR = $DB_NAME_MIR.Replace('<B>',$TIMESTAMPP);

    #Debugging....
    #Write-Host $DB_NAME_MIRROR;
    #Write-Host $STORAGE_URI_BACKUP;



    foreach ($DBB in $DB_ARRAYY) 
    {
        $DB_NAME_MIRR = $DB_NAME_MIR.Replace('<A>',$DBB);


       #Debugging
        #Write-Host $DB_NAME_MIRR   
        #Write-Host $URL_FILE_BACKUP 




    $SQL_SERVER_FULLNAME_QA = getSQLServerFullNameAzureQA;
    $TIMEOUT = 300;

    $QUERY 
    /* Nombre usado en la URL */
    SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM                       = 'buin',
                  @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD      = 'Sitio Mirror - Buin (20180109)',      
                  @URL_DOM                   = 'mrgbuin.demo.cl',
                  @DB_DOM                    = 'mirroring_dbdom_buin(2018-01-09-07:00)'
```

necesito que esta parte del código en las partes que dice buin vaya cambiando según la información de la array cuando se vaya ejecutando

```
 /* Nombre usado en la URL */
    SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM                       = 'buin',
                  @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD      = 'Sitio Mirror - Buin (20180109)',      
                  @URL_DOM                   = 'mrgbuin.demo.cl',
                  @DB_DOM                    = 'mirroring_dbdom_buin(2018-01-09-07:00)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hector,

El código no ha quedado muy claro, y falta información. Por ejemplo:

```
$DB_NAME_MIR = $DB_NAME_MIR.Replace('<B>',$TIMESTAMPP);
```

No puedes reemplazar un valor de algo que no declaraste anteriormente.
Fuera de ello, si no entendí mal lo que necesitas es lo siguiente:

```
$array = @( "elquisco", "imelbosque", "macul", "lareina", "mpinto", "penalolen", "coquimbo");
foreach ($item in $array) {
    Write-host "SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM='$item', @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD='Sitio Mirror - $item (20180109)', @URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl', @DB_DOM='mirroring_dbdom_$item(2018-01-09-07:00)'"
}
```

Así obtienes como resultado:

```
SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM='elquisco', @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD='Sitio Mirror - elquisco (20180109)', @URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl', @DB_DOM='mirroring_dbdom_elquisco(2018-01-09-07:00)'
SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM='imelbosque', @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD='Sitio Mirror - imelbosque (20180109)', @URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl', @DB_DOM='mirroring_dbdom_imelbosque(2018-01-09-07:00)'
SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM='macul', @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD='Sitio Mirror - macul (20180109)', @URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl', @DB_DOM='mirroring_dbdom_macul(2018-01-09-07:00)'
SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM='lareina', @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD='Sitio Mirror - lareina (20180109)', @URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl', @DB_DOM='mirroring_dbdom_lareina(2018-01-09-07:00)'
SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM='mpinto', @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD='Sitio Mirror - mpinto (20180109)', @URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl', @DB_DOM='mirroring_dbdom_mpinto(2018-01-09-07:00)'
SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM='penalolen', @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD='Sitio Mirror - penalolen (20180109)', @URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl', @DB_DOM='mirroring_dbdom_penalolen(2018-01-09-07:00)'
SELECT @NOMBRE_DOM='coquimbo', @NOMBRE_MUNICIPALIDAD='Sitio Mirror - coquimbo (20180109)', @URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl', @DB_DOM='mirroring_dbdom_coquimbo(2018-01-09-07:00)'
```

En donde se ha modificado lo que tu indicas. El único punto donde no se ha modificado es en la URL (*@URL_DOM='mrgbuin.demo.cl'*) ya que no es lo suficientemente claro si se debe modificar o no ese valor.

Espero haber ayudado!